# Best place to place organization structured data

Tags: seo, schema.org, structured-data

Where is the best place to place structured data about your organization? Is it best to place it on every page or on just the home of your website?

I am referring to:

```
http://schema.org/Organization
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wherever you provide information about your organization.

For example, if you have the organization’s contact information in the footer of every page, you can (may, not must) mark this up (in the same way) on all these pages.

This especially makes sense if you need the `Organization` item as value for a property, like [`author`](http://schema.org/author) of the [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage). (But you could also just give the URI that represents the organization as value.)

Comment: I see that websites do it just on the landing page to their site. Is this sufficient?

Comment: @BrendanVogt: It’s hard to say what counts as "sufficient" unless we talk about a specific consumer; they might all have different "rules". For example, Google Search doesn’t seem to show Rich Snippets for a site’s homepage (but in case of `Organization` this doesn’t matter as they don’t have a matching Rich Snippet, afaik).

Answer (score 1):

If your site is about *ymyl*, *your money or your life*, you should place your contact data on every single page, the nearer to the opening `<body>` tag, the better.

I would recommend to integrate a `JSON-LD` snippet - on this way you do it once for the whole site.

**JSON-LD snippet generator**: https://www.jamesdflynn.com/development/json-ld-markup-generator

Comment: I see that websites do it just on the landing page to their site. Is this sufficient?